# AccessControl : Require login to open a controller in yii2 :

Tags: yii2

I am working with a lot of module in yii2 like this.

```
yii_basic
   -- modules
         -- admin
         -- it
         -- members
```

I have a scenario which is the user (members) need an approval sign via email that sending by app.

For example, this is the link : `dzil.local/it/request/update?id=940` , which is this link is actually an update controller with ID.

I need user to force login when it's accessed.
But My problem is, after login is success, it 's not redirect to the controller that I mean: `dzil.local/it/request/update?id=940` but to actionIndex of module.

This is the class RequestController :

```
class RequestController extends Controller {
  public function behaviors() {
   return [
    'verbs' => [
    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
    'actions' => [
      'delete' => ['post'],
      'bulk-delete' => ['post'],
    ],
  ],

  'access' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
      [
        'actions' => ['create', 'update', 'delete', 'get-item-detail', 'error'],
        'allow' => true,
      ],
      [
        'actions' => ['logout', 'index'], // add all actions to take guest to login page
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['@'],
      ],
    ],
  ],

];
}
```

I think the failed it comes from this :

```
  public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        if (Yii::$app->user->can('Administrator')) {
            return $this->redirect(['/admin']);

        } else if (Yii::$app->user->can('IT')) { // the user is on IT
            return $this->redirect(['/it']);

        } else { //defaultnya user common
            return $this->redirect(['/members']); // the user is member
        }
    }

    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Please advise me to get a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  a go back  routing after login you should add where needed `return $this->goBack();`  eg:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model->login()) {
    return $this->goBack();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew return $this->goBack(); but I separated between module afterLogin and beforeLogin logic.